# Identify the cell containing a particular class using javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
var output = '<tr>'+
               '<td class="class1">One</td>'+
               '<td class="selected">Two</td>'+
               '<td></td>'+
               '<td></td>'
            '</tr>';
```

How can I identify which cell (1,2,3 or 4) has the `class="selected"`

Comment: I need the number of the cell. $('.selected') would select that cell with class='selected' and allow operations on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log($(output).find('.selected').index());
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KA9Cz/)**

And remember that [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is zero-based.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the position of element.

```
$(".selected", $(output)).index()
```

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements, [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have put that HTML in the page and rendered it, you can find out by finding the cell and then using [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index), which will give you its 0-based index relative to its siblings:

```
console.log($(".selected").index()); // 1, in your example
```

Of course, that will give you the information for the first element with the `selected` class anywhere on the page. To limit it to a given row, get a reference to the row (say, in a variable called `$tr`), then:

```
console.log($tr.children(".selected").index());
```